# Convert date format to insert into mysql db

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have pandas column `row['date']` which contains date in format `11/05/2015`. I am trying to insert it into mysql db but having problems due to incorrect format of date field data. It has to be converted into `2015-11-05` in order to be inserted. Without storing the new value in variable how can I convert the date into required format?

```
Current format: 11/05/2015
Required format: 2015-11-05
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String In Python to insert into MySQL DB date column date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422470/convert-string-in-python-to-insert-into-mysql-db-date-column-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the current format mm/dd/yyyy? If so

```
from datetime import datetime
row['date'] = datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I didn't want to further clutter the code so here is what I did and this is ready by my sql query using .format.

`datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: You might even be able to send the datetime object to the database depending on how your MySQL adaptor works.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dateutil.parser](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html),

> This module offers a generic date/time string parser which is able to parse most known formats to represent a date and/or time.

Here is a MWE.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

current_date = '11/05/2015'
required_date = parse(current_date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

---

PS: to explicitly distinguish between `DM` and `MD`, pass the argument `dayfirst=True/False` to `parse`, i.e. `dayfirst=True` represents `DM` and `dayfirst=False` represents `MD`.

Comment: `Explicit is better than implicit.`

I'd say its better to be explicit about what format you are converting from. 11/05/2015 could be either dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @Mat, thx, then add the argument `dayfirst=False` (the default value) to `parse`.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job, w/o needing `datetime`:

```
"{2}-{0}-{1}".format(*(original_date.split("/")))
```

Comment: I think you're better off using datetime rather than mangling the string. Reading this line as is the intent is not clear.

Comment: Not disagreeing; just providing an option.